# Android Data Binding for alternative layouts declares differing root layout as View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I am using Data Binding for the very first time. Everything was working as expected till I decided to create separate layout for landscape mode. Now, I have two layouts for main activity, respectively for portrait and landscape modes:

*activity_main.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--Some Views-->

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

*activity_main.xml (land)*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!--Some Views-->

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

The problem is that I am unable to use `binding.mainLayout` as a `ViewGroup` because it is declared as a view in `ActivityMainBinding.java`:

```
public final android.view.View mainLayout;
```

Shouldn't it be declared as a `ViewGroup`, seeing that both [`LinearLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) and [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) directly extend `ViewGroup`? Am I doing something wrong? Is there a logical reason behind this or is it just an oversight?

Answer (score 3):

Together with **ActivityMaindBinding**, you should get autogenerated implementation for default & land layouts. They should be called **ActivityMainBindingImpl** and **ActivityMainBindingLandImpl**  respectively.

In the runtime you can check with instanceof operator which one of the implemenations is in the use and access mainLayout with a proper type.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I'm not looking for a workaround (which I'm sure could be done in many ways). I'm curious about the reason for this behavior.

Comment: I've created an issue about this in google issues tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62740925 Let's see how they will respond

Comment: What can cause ActivityMainBindingImpl to not be generated?